# I'm trying to add a headline below name in this template but can't figure out how to add it

Tags: cv, resume

How do I add the headline "Business Analyst, Data Analyst, Project Management, Information Systems" below the name?

[image]

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{Rishi Shah} % Your name
\address{156 Kasturi, Balajinagar, Sangli 416416} % Your address
%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(+91)9975808780 \\ rishishah105@gmail.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}
```

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 1):

To bring this to an end please add the following code into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def \jobtitle#1{\def\@jobtitle{#1}}
\def \printjobtitle {%
  \begingroup
    \centerline{\large\bf\@jobtitle}
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

\def \printname {%
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
  \printjobtitle
}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

It adds an `\jobtitle` after the printed name. So we have also to add the line

```
\jobtitle{Business Analyst, Data Analyst, Project Management, Information Systems}
```

into the preamble to define the `\jobtitle` to be printed ...

So based on a template cv example with your given name etc try the following complete code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (8/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Trey Hunner (http://www.treyhunner.com/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the resume.cls file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The resume.cls file provides the resume style used for structuring the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def \jobtitle#1{\def\@jobtitle{#1}}
\def \printjobtitle {%
  \begingroup
    \centerline{\large\bf\@jobtitle}
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

\def \printname {%
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
  \printjobtitle
}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\name{Rishi Shah} % Your name
\address{156 Kasturi, Balajinagar, Sangli 416416} % Your address
%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(+91)9975808780 \\ rishishah105@gmail.com} % Your phone number and email
\jobtitle{Business Analyst, Data Analyst, Project Management, Information Systems} % <=================


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University} \hfill {\em Graduated October 2017} 
\\ B.CSc. Computer Science


\end{rSection}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{STI Technologies Limited}{May 2015 - April 2016}{Oracle Database Developer (Co-op)}{Data Solutions Department}
\item Completed two internships, first as a data analyst, then as a database developer
\item Developed web scrapers to collect physician data using both Python and CasperJS. Trained colleagues in how to operate and maintain these scrapers. The resulting data was later used to develop a suite of physician-focused reports.
\item Built a highly efficient Fellegi-Sunter record linkage procedure in PL/SQL to merge several sources of physician data.
\item Created complex SQL queries for both internal and external clients, and helped those clients understand the results through both electronic and in-person consultation.
\item Developed Python, batch and PowerShell scripts to automate data entry, report modification, data extraction and other labor intensive tasks, saving hundreds of man hours.
\item Wrote extensive documentation for all of the above projects.
\end{rSubsection}


%------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSubsection}{Course Work \& Extracurriculars}{}{}{}

\item Contributed to the open source ReviewBoard Django application, integrating social authentication in order to validate GitHub webhooks and merge users.
\item Developed interconnected RESTful web services in NodeJS as a part of my Cloud Computing course.
\item In the Software Engineering course, using SVN and in a team of four, developed an Android application in Vaadin (Java) which allowed the user to tag their current location with graffiti, and see nearby graffiti.
\item As a part of the Machine Learning course, implemented and used several unsupervised, supervised and reinforcement learning models in MATLAB and learned the theory behind them.
\item Built a multithreaded HTTP server in C as part of the Operating Systems course. The server used three different queuing strategies.
\item Completed the nand2tetris course, building a full-scale computer system and simple compiler and assembler starting from basic logic circuits.
\item Was the 2016 Tabs Director \& Organizational Committee Member of the Dalhousie debate team. Made it to the finals of several debate tournaments and won multiple awards.

\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{rSection}{Technologies}

\itab{\textbf{Languages}}                \tab{{Python, Java, Javascript, C++, C, Oracle}}

\itab{\textbf{Libraries \& Frameworks}}  \tab{{NodeJS, Django, Vaadin, numpy, pandas, Tensorflow}}

\itab{\textbf{Software}}                 \tab{{LaTeX, UNIX, Eclipse, Jetbrains, Jupyter, git}}

\end{rSection}


\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]