# How to move name, address, phone, email to the middle and add a headline below it?

Tags: moderncv, letters, cv

I am trying to create my cover letter with class `moderncv` but I don't quite know how to move the name, address, phone, email to the top center of the page. I would like to make it look like the one in second picture (it's a screenshot of a word document).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}                            

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}

\phone[mobile]{0123-123456789}               
\email{john@doe.com}                             


\begin{document}

\recipient{To}{Employer}
\date{\today}
\opening{Hi!}
\closing{Thanks in advance!}
\enclosure[Attachment]{CV}
\makelettertitle
```

[image]

That is want I want to get:

[image]

## EDIT:

Thank you again for the suggestion. I have almost everything I need for the cover letter except for the address part. When I add the address below name, it creates space between the address and the phone/email. I tried reducing the space but it didn't work. How can I reduce the space? Thanks!

```
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{111 nowhere street}{nowhere, nw}{11111}
\phone {(111)-111-111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Probably you are more satisfied with the `banking` style. For an example output see here: http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_banking_red.pdf

Comment: Yeah, banking style sounds good. However, it is a resume and I'm looking to integrate that style on my cover letter.

Comment: Page 4 of the above mentioned example document shows the corresponding cover letter.

Comment: @leandriis where do I find that template? 
edit: I found it.

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). **That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"**

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has two parts:

1. Choose the right/best layout for the cover letter
2. Add the title at the proper place

Because you did not tell us if you build your cv and the cover letter in one file I guess you do ...

So you have first to change for the cover letter the used head (it is easier to use an already existing layout than to complete rewrite the code for the header ...) like this:

```
\title{title of the job} % <============================================
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}
```

Command `\moderncvhead{3}` uses the header used in style `banking` and with the following `patchcmd` I simply deleted the predefined title. We add the missing title with the code:

```
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
      \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother
```

Please see that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed to be able to use `@` in the code ...

Of course you can use another value instead my used `2em` to define the space between the title and the following `To:` in line

```
\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
```

So please see the following complete mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % <================================ classic banking head 3, body 3
\moderncvcolor{green}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}

\phone[mobile]{0123-123456789}
\email{john@doe.com}

\title{title of the job} % <============================================
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% <=============================
  {}%
  {error}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\recipient{To}{Employer}
\date{\today}
\opening{Hi!}
\closing{Thanks in advance!}
\enclosure[Attachment]{CV}
\makelettertitle

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting cover letter]

## EDIT (for first comment):

To get a smaller gap between the name and the jobtitle add the following code

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}
```

Change my used `[1em]` to a value fitting your needs ...

See the complete mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % <================================ classic banking head 3, body 3
\moderncvcolor{green}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}

\phone[mobile]{0123-123456789}
\email{john@doe.com}

\title{title of the job} % <============================================
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% <=================================================
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\recipient{To}{Employer}
\date{\today}
\opening{Hi!}
\closing{Thanks in advance!}
\enclosure[Attachment]{CV}
\makelettertitle

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result two]

## EDIT (for your edit in question):

You need to add another patch to the code:

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}% <=================================================
  {\\\null}%
  {\\}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}
```

With the complete mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % <================================ classic banking head 3, body 3
\moderncvcolor{green}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{111 nowhere street}{nowhere, nw}{11111}
\phone {(111)-111-111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}

\title{title of the job} % <============================================
\moderncvhead{3} % <====================================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% <=================================================
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% <=================================================
  {\\\null}%
  {\\}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\recipient{To}{Employer}
\date{\today}
\opening{Hi!}
\closing{Thanks in advance!}
\enclosure[Attachment]{CV}
\makelettertitle

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image: result three]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the cover letter is a separate document. It is not part of the resume. I was able to add the title/headline below my address. However, there is a big gap between the name and the title of the job. How do I reduce it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have one more question when I add address below the name, it creates a space between the address and the phone/email. How do I reduce the space between the address and phone/email?

As for the resume, I already made a post. You replied to that post with a link to adding a line below the name/address. However, I want to add the "title of the job" below the address just like the cover letter. Here is the link to the post:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501996/im-trying-to-add-a-headline-below-name-in-this-template-but-cant-figure-out-ho

Comment: @AbhinavKonagala Please **do not use** this outdated class `resume.cls` and please note the code you gave there is not compilable!). Why do you not use class `moderncv` for your cv too, then you can keep cover letter and cv in one file ...